# How to customize UISearchBar in iOS7 (Clear button)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to customise the `UISearchBar` clear button. I can set a custom image for the icon in normal state but I don't know how to set the same image for the state when I've got a finger on the button. It always has the system look. I tried to set the same image for all available states but failed to obtain any results.

for iOS7:

```
    [self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_X_black.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_X_black.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted]; /// doesn't work
```

No changes when I set the same for `UIControlStateHighlighted` or `UIControlStateSelected`. Is it possible to customise this button in iOS7? In iOS6 when I set the same icon for `UIControlStateHighlighted` it works correctly.

for iOS6:

```
    [self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_X_black.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_X_black.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted]; /// it works
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its odd but your cant use the same image to go from Normal to heightlight, try changing the image of the second call

Comment: @ShamsAhmed as you said if images are the same it doesn't work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very strange behavior of iOS7 but the solution is the reverse order of statements in code if you want to set the same image for two states

```
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_X_black"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_X_black"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Also you can duplicate you icon_X_black file under different names and use any order.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on `UISearchBar`:

> *state*
>
> A control state.
>
> Valid states are `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateDisabled`.

Seems like `UIControlStateHighlighted` isn't supported here.

Comment: @malex There's a difference between "It works" and "It's supported". Apple clearly states what states are valid. It might work for now, but it could easily break in future releases of iOS.

Comment: I understand. But in my practice I prefer to solve the problem as "it works" because iOS evaluation shows that a lot of formally unsupported features has very long life :)